# Linq Get a list of items from a list of items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a service that returns an `IQueryable<Criteria>`. `Criteria` can have many `Attribute`s and an `Attribute` can have one `AttributeType`.

Here are the model classes :

```
public class Criteria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)] public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Highlight { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IList<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public AttributeType Type { get; set; }
    public AttributeOperation Operation { get; set; }
    public IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

My `CriteriaService` uses a base service to return `IQueryable<Criteria>`. The base service method looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets all the entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="includes">Option includes for eager loading</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<T> List(params string[] includes)
    {
        // Create a query
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbEntitySet;

        // For each include, append to our query
        if (includes != null) 
             foreach (var include in includes) 
                 query = query.Include(include);

        // Return our query
        return query;
    }
```

Now I want to return all the `AttributeTypes` for a given category. So I have started creating a method which looks like this:

```
public List<AttributeType> List(int categoryId)
{
    var query = _criteriaService.Value.List(categoryId, "attributes.type").Select(m => m.Attributes);
    // TODO: How to get a list of Types from the Attribute
    return new List<AttributeType>();
}
```

But I am unsure how I can get all the `AttributeTypes` from each `Attribute`.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all `AttributeTypes` for a given `Criteria` object?

Comment: I suppse you can use `_criteriaService.Value.List(...).SelectMany(m => m.Attributes.Select(y => y.Type))`

Comment: List is probably an undesirable method name (at least for me) here...

Comment: Note that the `Include` is ignored here because the end result contains attributetypes, not criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) which flattens your list of lists into a single list:

```
var query = _criteriaService.Value.List(categoryId, "attributes.type")
    .SelectMany(m => m.Attributes)
    .Select(y => x.Type);
```

Comment: Because of the way queryables work under the hood, you're better off using `SelectMany(...).Select(...)` instead of `SelectMany(...Select(...))`

Comment: still lightly wrong @HimBromBeere, it should be `var query = _criteriaService.Value.List(categoryId, "attributes.type").SelectMany(m => m.Attributes).Select(m => m.Type);`

Comment: Both query shapes are 100% equivalent in this case. The original answer wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As above, `SelectMany` is generally what you want.

Notably you're better off using as much Linq code as possible, since the usual use of `IQueryable` over `IEnumerable` is because it converts into some other kind of code under the hood, such as SQL queries, and thus isn't being done step by step in C# memory.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that :) that's why my services return IQuerable, but thanks anyway!